# Cookie with no name in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, names

I was trying to set cookie name from a variable, and I accidentally deleted the variable declaration, which lead to an intersting discovery. Consider the code below:

```
setcookie('', 'value', time()+10);
```

I assumed that this code shouldn't work since we need to declare a name for the cookie, and respectively should output an error, but instead it sets the cookie with name that is contained in the **value**, and the value of the cookie is equal to an empty string `''` instead:

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);  // array (size=1) 'value' => string '' (length=0)
setcookie('', 'value', time()+10);  
echo (int)isset($_COOKIE['value']);  // 1
```

Can someone explain please why that happens? I'm just trying to think that potentially there could be a situation when this might happen and cause a lot of confusion, although you should check everything for mistakes in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The cookies are stocked like a GET parameters.

For exemple :

```
setCookie('a', 'A');
setCookie('b', 'B');
```

Will be stored as :

```
a=A&b=B
```

I assume that, if the key is empty, an url_encode will display this :

```
setCookie('', 'A');
setCookie('b', 'B');

A&b=B
```

Wich can be read as :

```
A = "";
b = "B";
```

Comment: Adding `?A&B` to the script will store keys in GET like `$_GET['A']` and `$_GET['B']` with empty strings, that I kind of understand, it would be the same as having `setcookie('A');`, but why does it work like that with an empty string for a name I wonder

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:
Looking at the [source of setcookie](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/93f0b8142bda63b4102feac605521ccc7d46bf21/ext/standard/head.c#L127) the format used to build the `Set-Cookie` header line is `Set-Cookie: %s=%s`. So, i'm not a C programmer, but **maybe** C's [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) doesn't replace the first parameter `name` (which would be an empty string) and starts replacing the format-string with the second additional parameter `value` as the first.